# Facing the below issue after upgrade flutter sdk

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

[image]

After upgrading flutter sdk I faced this issue. I have done clean and pub get but still can't solve this problem.

- Flutter 3.13.8 • channel stable
- Dart 3.1.4

  1. isDefinedAndNotNull => The property 'isDefinedAndNotNull' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'. Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').

  Type: Invalidtype

  2. The getter 'isUndefinedOrNull' isn't defined for the type 'List'.
     Try importing the library that defines 'isUndefinedOrNull', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'isUndefinedOrNull'.

  Type: Invalidtype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isDefinedAndNotNull` & `isUndefinedOrNull` are part of the JS interlop library for dart.

```dart
import 'dart:js_interop';
```

However, In dart variables are always defined. They're either null or have a value.

So, The code in the first image, the if condition becomes redundant. Since what it's assigned to and it self can be null.

```dart
// this below
complaintSketch.isDefinedAndNotNull ? complaintSketch : null
// is same as
complaintSketch
```

In your second code the list `List<Points> points` in not nullable. So you may skip the null check:

```dart
List<Points> points = _controller!.value;
if (points.isEmpty) return;
```